# Why isn't my Webpack Sass configuration working?

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack

I'm trying to set up Sass loading in my Webpack project.

I've installed `node-sass`, `sass-loader`, `css-loader`, and `style-loader`, as you can see from my **package.json** dependencies:

```
//...
"dependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.14.0",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1"
  "express": "^4.14.0",
  "react": "^15.3.1",
  "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
  "webpack": "^1.13.2",
  "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6
},
"devDependencies": {
  "css-loader": "^0.24.0",
  "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
  "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
  "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
  "webpack": "^1.13.2",
  "webpack-validator": "^2.2.7"
}
//...
```

I've added the loaders in **webpack.config.js**:

```
//...
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loaders: ['babel'],
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
    },
  ],
},
//...
```

...and added this to my **main.js**:

```
import '../stylesheets/main.scss';
```

That SCSS file includes some simple, obvious color changes:

```
button {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

When I start the server, I get this output at the end:

```
  [174] ./stylesheets/main.scss 1.02 kB {0} [built]
  [175] ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./stylesheets/main.scss 250 bytes {0} [built]
  [176] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 1.51 kB {0} [built]
  [177] ./~/style-loader/addStyles.js 7.15 kB {0} [built]
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

Which seems to suggest that my CSS is being processed appropriately. But in the browser, there's no evidence of any CSS. No changes are visible on the page, no styles are visible in the inspector. I'm not sure what else I should be looking for.

Did I miss an important step? What else should I try to make it work?

Comment: this have nothing to do with webpack, u are probably importing the wrong file or in the wrong place.

Comment: @ZeRubeus I'm not sure what you mean. How can I import the right file in the right place? This is a very small project with only one JS file, one HTML file, and one SCSS file so far, so there aren't exactly a lot of possibilities here as far as which file to import where.

Comment: can you post your html and js files please ?

Comment: @ZeRubeus Never mind, I figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My CSS configuration was correct. This issue seems to have been caused by an outdated copy of **bundle.js** left over from an earlier manual compile, which was being loaded instead of the current version on the dev server. When I removed the file, it worked immediately.

Comment: told u, have nothing to do with webpack :)